# How to center images in a div with fixed height using Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jsp

I want to make a fixed size of `<div>` with images in it.
I have this `jsp` part (if needed more, I will add)

```
<html>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<head>
<!-- Required meta tags -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="carousel-inner">
 <div class="carousel-item active">
  <img style="margin-top: 5px; max-width: 350px; max-height: 200px; display:block; margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto" src="img/${i.imageURLs.get(0)}" height="200" width="350">
 </div>
 <c:forEach var="img" items="${i.imageURLs}">
  <c:if test="${img != i.imageURLs.get(0)}">
   <div class="carousel-item">
    <img style="margin-top: 5px; max-width: 350px; max-height: 200px; display: block; margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto" src="img/${img}" height="200" width="350">
   </div>
  </c:if>
 </c:forEach>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS is

```
img {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    margin-top: auto;
}
```

It is the representation of `jsp` page with the image URLs collection inside of it. The problem is that pictures with not proper height make my `div`'s height less and all the square becomes smaller (at least, proportions are fine).

[image: what i want everywhere] [image: what I see xd]

How to set the `<img>` style properly to center them vetically, or make the bottom margins dynamic depending on image's height?
Without `width: auto; height: auto;` there's no needed result so I supposed to use both styles from `<img>` and CSS.

Comment: Not sure if this'll help: you can set your image's `height` (instead of `max-height`) to `200px` and use `object-fit: contain` on it to make it fit inside the defined size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [chriskirknielsen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3624336/chriskirknielsen) said, the `object-fit: contain` and setting the `max-height: 200px` to `height: 200px` had made the expected behaviour.

Comment: Happy it worked! Make sure to provide prefixes and a good fallback experience if your planned support includes older browsers. 

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.

```html
.image-parent {
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

I fixed parent on `200px` so that every parent will be same height.

`align-items: center;` will center content of the parent on vertical axis which should solve your problem

I also added ``` max-width: 100%`` and ```height: auto`for images to make them responsive. For this you can use bootstrap4 class`img-fluid`or bootstrap3`img-responsive```

You can

Answer (score -2):

On the image tag, Add alignment to be center

```
<img style="margin-top: 5px; **align: center;** max-width: 350px; max-height: 200px; display:block; margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto" src="img/${i.imageURLs.get(0)}" height="200" width="350" >
```

Comment: Nope, `align` is unknown property according to IDE (and no visible results on the page)

Comment: The `align` property does no exist in CSS.